# Background problem on section tag from top

Tags: html, css, background, frontend, sections

I set the background to the section and get a small margin from the top. F12 not show margin between section. Margin on top section-tag

```
.section1{background-size:cover;}
```

HTML (views)

Here I get margin between top start page and section - 1 white color line. But not margin  on F12

```
@section('content')
<section class="section1">    
@include('games. hai.sidebar')
<div class="section1_content">
</div>
<section>
@end
```

I do not have margin and padding. What is the reason for this?

Comment: please put a sample of your current code

Comment: I edit question

Comment: what is your background ? picture, vidoe ? link ? you can use built in code IDE to mimic the issue

Comment: just picture. It look like have margin.  ANd after section start. But actualy no margin and background without white line.

Comment: could you post a screenshots ? It getting hard to under the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I deciede problem:
For delete white margin on top section tag need to css add overflow:hidden;